# Make text in paraghapghs in div overflow instead of new lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say I have several pretty longs lines in a paragraph:

```
<div style="overflow: auto"> 
    <p> 
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
    </p> 
    <p> 
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
    </p> 
</div>
```

and window width less that width of the pahagraph (a's + b's + c's). Currently scroll will appear only if width of any of components (a, b, or c) is more that width of the window and over components are carried to the new lines. I want contents of each paragraph appear on the same line with a scroll. How can I treat each paraghaph as a string, so contents of the paragraph is treated like a single line?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With CSS you can do:

```
p {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto
}
```

This make the spaces non-breaking, so the paragraph will all be on one line.

Comment: You've got to be kidding! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set [white-space:nowrap](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) and `overflow:auto` property of css. You can assign a `class` to paragraph tag for which you want text on single line.

*CSS*

```
.className {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

*Html*

```
<div style="overflow: auto"> 
    <p class="className"> 
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
    </p> 
    <p class="className"> 
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
    </p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Either add styles as below

```
p{
    overflow:auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

or use jQuery as below

```
$('p').css('overflow','auto');
$('p').css('white-space','nowrap');
```

Here is a live fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/qmCwL/

Comment: Just curious, why not `$('p').css({overflow: 'auto', whiteSpace: 'nowrap'});` ?